# Redirect only error to log file from console consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka console consumer, and i  want to redirect error thrown from kafka process to a log file. Requirement is such that if a process runs without error i redirect output of my topic to a file and am using command like `kafka-console-consumer --topic example --group-id mygroup -bootstrap-server broker:9092 --from-beginning --property print.key=true` . Now if there is an error while say connecting to topic or permission on say group id , i want that error to be redirected to a file say `/tmp/myerrors.txt` ( errors thrown by kafka or system error ) but in case there is no issues and i start getting data for the topic i redirect data to another file `\home\abcd\data.txt` . Is it feasible ? I want it so that error and data files are separate and due to an issue on mid-day my files which is meant for collecting data does not get the error logged into it.

Comment: I suggest you actually write code for this, but have you tried using regular shell redirection? `kafka-console-consumer... 1> regular.log 2> errors.log`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes that does not help. Errors from Kafka such as not permissioned for a topic or to a group id goes to regular.logs instead of errors.log